# Nav Bar Menu Disappear

Tags: php, html, css

I need some help with this php code please... Ive been trying to fix the problem with the nav bar holder.

```
/* CSS overwrites for new navigation */
#nav li .drop {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/dd-back.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 44px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.65);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.65);   
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
#nav li .drop2 {
    width: 496%;
}
#nav li .drop ul li {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-top: 0px solid #4f4e50;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 19px 4px 18px;
    height: 24px;
}
#nav li .drop2 ul li {
    width: 42%;
}

.primary-menu li .sub-menu li a {
    color: #fdfdfe;
    display: block;
    font-family: myriad-pro,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 3px 0px 4px 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-image: none !important;
}

#nav li .drop ul li a:hover {
    background: #2d2d2f !important;
}




@media only screen and (max-device-width : 768px) { 

    .nav-holder{
    display:none;   
    }
    
    .site-header-menu{
    display:none;   
    }
    
    div{
    max-width:100% !important;  
    }
    
    img{
    max-width: 100% !important; 
    }
    
    body{
    max-width: 100% !important; 
        min-width:100% !important;

    }
    html{
    max-width: 100% !important; 
    }
    
    body, html, img, div, span, ul, h1, h2, h3, li, header, footer{
    max-width: 100% !important; 
    }
    
    .inner-page #twocolumns {
    background-image: none !important;
}
    
    .logo {
    margin: 0 0 15px 20px !important;
    
    background-image: url(images/logo.png) !important;

    max-width: 100% !important;
    background-size: 280px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
    .entry-header {
    background: #666;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 10px 5px 1px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

    .header-box .box {
  
    height: auto !important;
    background: #ccc !important;
        max-width:100%;
        min-width:100%;
        text-align:center !important;
    
}
    
.header {
    width: 100% !important
    ;
}
}
```

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=SITE_MIN_WIDTH, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php if ( is_singular() && pings_open( get_queried_object() ) ) : ?>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/mzf6nuq.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-8444662-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <div class="holder">
                        <div class="frame">
<ul><li class="first"><a href="/" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/" title="Employment" >Employment</a></li>
<li><a href="/" title="Email Us" >Email Us</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="/search" title="Search" >Search</a></li>
</ul>
<form id="searchForm" action="search" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <span class="text"><input type="text" name="customSearch" value="Search Site" /></span>
        <input type="submit" id="searchField" class="btn-search" value="Search" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="56" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="header-box">
                    <h1 class="logo"><a href="/">We're the People</a></h1>
                    <div class="box">
                        <!--
<ul>
<li><strong>Call Us</strong> <span></span></li>
<li><strong>24 Service</strong> <span>Serving CT &amp; NYC</span></li>
</ul>
-->
<ul>
<li><strong>24 Service</strong> <span>New York &amp; CT<br /><a href="tel:"></a></span><span>New York<br /><a href=""></a></span></li>
</ul>

                  <!-- Begin Signup Form -->

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-holder">
                
                <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) || has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>
                    <button id="menu-toggle" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?></button>
  
                    <div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
                        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
                            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                                     ) );
                                ?>
                            </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div><!-- .site-header-menu -->
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- .site-header-main -->

            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                <?php
                
                    /**
                     * Filter the default twentysixteen custom header sizes attribute.
                     *
                     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
                     *
                     * @param string $custom_header_sizes sizes attribute
                     * for Custom Header. Default '(max-width: 709px) 85vw,
                     * (max-width: 909px) 81vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px'.
                     */
                    $custom_header_sizes = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_custom_header_sizes', '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 81vw, (max-width: 1362px) 88vw, 1200px' );
                ?>
                <div class="header-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( get_custom_header()->attachment_id ) ); ?>" sizes="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_header_sizes ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
                    </a>
                </div><!-- .header-image -->
            <?php endif; // End header image check. ?>
               
                </div>
```

I checked the html and css I tried to do as much as I possible know; I don't see where the problem is... I just gave up lol i did some changes in css I am able to make the nav bar appears in the mobile devices. however, the menu items are not showing up in small screens. it does to the bottom in mobile devices.

Comment: Where is the `echo()`?

Comment: What does the HTML look like for the nav in the page source? It would help to know what the CSS is affecting by what your structure looks like.